# how to sampling the output layer in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Say if I have a model of 1024 output classes. But each time of prediction, I only want to randomly predict 10 of the 1024 classes. Anyone has clues about how to implement it in keras?

```
            class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):

                def __init__(self, deep_col):
                    super(MyModel, self).__init__()
                    self.feature_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns=deep_col)
                    self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')
                    self.dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu)
                    self.dense3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation=tf.nn.relu)
                    self.dense4 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation=tf.nn.softmax)

                def call(self, input_tensor):
                    y = self.feature_layer(input_tensor)
                    y = self.dense1(y)
                    y = self.dense2(y)
                    y = self.dense3(y)
                    y = self.dense4(y)

                    TODO: select 10 out of the random classes

                    return y
``
```

Comment: You can generate a prediction for all 1024 classes. Out of that array, you may select 12 classes.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal Of course I can do that, the problem is, if the class number is incredibly large, e.g., 1 million, but I only want to predict 10 of them. I waste all the time on meaningless computations.